# How to split list in a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm working with stacks, and I want to split the 'push' value. As a whole, this happens to just be a list in a tuple. I got (as output):

```
('_stack_', ['data inside the stack'])
```

and I'm looking to get this:

```
('_stack_',['data','inside','the','stack])
```

I gave this a try but it threw an error (note: 'Stack' is the variable that refers to the output above):

```
for i in Stack: 
    Stack[1].split()
```

If anyone could give me a hand, I assume even though this is a stack the same fundamentals of iterating through a tuple and lists should still hold true? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `tuple` are not mutable so you can't change the list in the tuple, you will need to recreate a new tuple. You don't need the for loop (you aren't using `i`). e.g. `tuple(Stack[0], Stack[1][0].split()`

Comment: This feels like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new tuple with the required values, like this:

```
t  = ('_stack_', ['data inside the stack'])
nt = (t[0], t[1][0].split())
```

Now `nt` is as expected:

```
nt
=> ('_stack_', ['data', 'inside', 'the', 'stack'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just hint, not full answer - maybe its full answer, because your main problem seems you cant split the string.... : You are trying to split list, you need to split string.
Tuple is immutable, so you need to transform to list and back to tuple, or make new tuple from original tuple elements

```
splitted_list = ('_stack_', ['data inside the stack'])[1][0].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner to create a new tuple using list comprehension

```
tuple([i[0].split() if isinstance(i,list) else i for i in your_tuple])
```

Output

```
('_stack_', ['data', 'inside', 'the', 'stack'])
```